# When I set up a user account restricted to port forwarding, `command="/bin/echo message"` blocks `permitopen`

Tags: networking, server, ssh, 19.10, tunnel

I'm trying to set up a user account that can only set up a tunnel for port forwarding on a specific port (9229). I've created the user with a minimal home folder (just a `.ssh` folder and `.ssh/authorized_keys` file). I've gotten the private key login working (and have since disabled password login). Now here is my `authorized_keys` file:

```
permitopen="localhost:9229",no-pty,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,command="/bin/echo 'Remote shell access has been disabled'" ssh-rsa KEY USER@HOST
```

Now when I try to set up the tunnel with `ssh -i KEY -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -L 9229:127.0.0.1:9229 USER@HOST sleep 10`, I just get `Remote shell access has been disabled`. If I remove the `command=...` part, there's no problem, but then the user can get up to all kinds of stuff.

What am I doing wrong?

I am basing my method on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021/allow-user-to-set-up-an-ssh-tunnel-but-nothing-else

I have tried moving the `permitopen` directive after and before the `command` directive. I also have tried `permitopen=127.0.0.1:9229` and `permitopen=:9229`.